# Pandas create a dataframe whose entries are relationships between rows of another dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following table in a csv.

```
 elementID | groupID | sequence
     abc   |    A    |    0
     dcv   |    A    |    1
     asd   |    B    |    1
     ccc   |    B    |    0
     abc   |    B    |    2
```

I imported this table in `Pandas` as a DataFrame.

From this DataFrame I need to create another one where each entry represents two two sequential elements of `elementID`.

For example something like the following

```
 elementID_1 | elementID_2 | groupID
     abc     |    dcv      |    A
     asd     |    abc      |    B
     ccc     |    asd      |    B
```

At first I thought of a multi-row selection but could not find out how to do that.

So I decided to do step by step creating one column per time.
I created first the column `elementID_2` as follows

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
new_df[["elementID_2", "sequence", "groupID"]] = old_df.loc[old_df.loc.sequence>1][["elementID", "sequence", "groupID"]]
```

Now to create the `elementID_1` column I would like to match the entries of the old dataframe having as`sequence` value, the `sequence` value of the new DataFrame minus 1 and the same `groupdID` between the two DataFrame.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can do so by `shift()` on groups and `dropna`:

```
df.sort_values('sequence', inplace=True)
df['elementID_1'] = df.groupby('groupID').elementID.shift()
df.dropna()
```

Output:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+---------------+
|    | elementID   | groupID   |   sequence | elementID_1   |
|----+-------------+-----------+------------+---------------|
|  1 | dcv         | A         |          1 | abc           |
|  2 | asd         | B         |          3 | ccc           |
|  4 | abc         | B         |          4 | asd           |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+---------------+
```

Then you can drop `sequence` column and rename `elementID` to `elementID_2`.

Comment: Should not it be sorted by `groupID` first and `sequence` as second?

Comment: No need to sort on `groupID` as `groupby` will take care of that. But there's no harm in doing so, if you need it in order as well.

Comment: There is an ambiguity in my question: indexes of `A` and `B` are not sequential: they might have they have the same values (for exampel `B` might be start from 0 again). That is why I am asking. I will correct my question.

Comment: It's doesn't matter. As long as you sort on `sequence`, they will appear in correct order in each `groupID`. Again, there's no harm to do extra work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way using `groupby` + `itertools`

```
s=df.groupby('groupID').elementID.apply(lambda x : set(itertools.combinations(x.values.tolist(), 2)))
df1=pd.DataFrame(s.index.repeat(s.str.len()))
df2=pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.chain(*s.tolist())))
pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
Out[286]: 
  groupID    0    1
0       A  abc  dcv
1       B  asd  abc
2       B  asd  ccc
3       B  ccc  abc
```

Comment: Almost...I tried on my original dataset and it seems in this way extra entries are created, for example an entry with `ccc` as first and `abc` as second.

Comment: @FrancescoBoi looks like just a shift problem then